# should linq to sql be used for websites that have high traffic

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq-to-sql

I have read many articles about linq to sql performance. The result which i got is it is slower than normal approach(DAL or Microsoft Enterprise library). *Slower for both read and write operations even after performance tuning* like disable ObjectTracking and other tricks. I know it has prons like quick development, clean code etc but what about the performance.

What if i used only for read operations.

Please give your suggestions.

Comment: +1 I dont think its LINQ to SQL as a whole but instead the fact its so deep, and so easy to do wrong. A misunderstood use of a collection property in a loop can lead to big performance issues fast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to work well enough for stackoverflow ;-p Especially if you use [compiled queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354245/linq-to-sql-compiledquery-compile-with-update-delete-insert), this is unlikely to be your bottleneck, compared (for example) to appropriate DB design and fetching the right columns / rows, and avoiding n+1 loading.

Comment: @Gravel && @Byers. one question. suppose we have 3 servers. 1 for read, 1 for write and the other is a replication server. so if i use linq for read operations and for write operation i use queries by hand. Is this the best solution? or is there any other best solution. what you suggest

Comment: @Adeel - db servers or app servers? It sounds like you mean the db server - but I'm not sure that the *specific* data-access API used is going to make a huge difference (compared to the different db setups)

Comment: @Gravel Server means Database Server. As linq approach is very slow for write operations compared to data access api, while for read the performance overhead is negligible. so it it better to use linq for only READ purposes?

Comment: @Adeel - certainly it is *better* at read than write; it really depends on the scenario, though; most code isn't issuing large amounts of DML. If you *do* have this, then command batching is desirable, but you might also consider firing the data down to the DB in bulk (for example xml or SqlBulkCopy, or in SQL 2008 table-valued parameters) and process it using set-based updates/inserts at the db. Only the first of these is available via L2S.

Comment: @Adeel: It depends on the specific queries you need to do. I'd probably try to measure the actual performance with LINQ first before giving up with it and choosing a different technology. There are many situations where it will work well for both read and write. But you say that you have already measured it and found it to be considerably slower. I'd probably double-check what queries it is actually sending to the DB to see if there is an obvious problem with an easy fix, and do some performance measuring to see where the time is lost, but otherwise I think you already have your answer there.

Comment: @Adeel: I would suggest using SqlBulkCopy, as suggested by Marc, as well as trying the batch update/delete implementation I linked to then benchmarking their performance. Without trying I agree with Mark that it would be too early to give up on. I'm actually about to implement this for my own measurement purposes but haven't gotten around to it yet so I have no numbers to share. Nonetheless, I would be surprised if performance didn't improve after shrinking it down to 1 query.

Answer (score 4):

For read operations LINQ To SQL should be roughly as fast as directly writing the SQL because that's exactly what it does. The overhead of creating the SQL shouldn't be noticable. There might be a few queries that it doesn't get as optimal as if you wrote the query by hand, but in my experience it does very well in most cases.

For bulk updates, LINQ To SQL is typically slower because it handles rows one at a time. You can't do something like `UPDATE Foo SET x = 0 WHERE id BETWEEN 100 AND 200` in LINQ to SQL without fetching all the rows. It's currently best to write the SQL by hand for this type of operation.

Answer (score 3):

The updates and deletes is where LINQ to SQL currently suffers since a separate statement is generated for each affected object.

That said, this blog post details how to get both operations down to 1 statement, which should help improve performance: [Batch Updates and Deletes with LINQ to SQL](http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx).

Compiled queries will also come in handy for frequently used queries, especially those where parameters are used to get specific results. You might also find this post helpful: [10 Tips to Improve your LINQ to SQL Application Performance](http://www.sidarok.com/web/blog/content/2008/05/02/10-tips-to-improve-your-linq-to-sql-application-performance.html).